# Using password_hash and password_verify from different objects in OO PHP

Tags: php

I'm writing an MVC style application using OO PHP and have run into an issue when trying to use different classes when trying to register/login users.  Essentially, I have an abstract User class holding some common properties and functions and 2 classes which extend this: a LoginUser class created when a user attempts to login and a RegisterUser class created when a user attempts to register.

My issue is this:  When I successfully add a user to my database using a query that is called in the RegisterUser class (using the password_hash function on the password) and then try to login via a query called in the LoginUser class (using the password_verify function) the query result returns false, even when the password supplied is definitely the password that was entered at registration.

My question is this: Does the password_verify function have to be called by an object of the same class that used the password_hash function to create the hash?  If so, why?  I have tried looking at the PHP documentation and search results do not return an answer either!

The reason that I ask this is because the registration/login will succeed if all of the functions are held in a single User class, instead of inherited classes.

My User class:

```
abstract class User {

protected $checkedUserName = '';
protected $checkedPassword = '';

public function __construct($uncheckedUserName, $uncheckedPassword) {

  $this->checkedUserName = $this->validateAndSanitizeUserName($uncheckedUserName);
  $this->checkedPassword = $this->validateAndSanitizePassword($uncheckedPassword);
}

protected function validateAndSanitizeUserName($uncheckedUserName) {
  $string = filter_var($uncheckedUserName, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL); // Checks input is an email
  $string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Removes illegal chars
  $string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); // Removes HTML tags, etc replacing them with char codes
  return $string;
}

protected function validateAndSanitizePassword($uncheckedPassword) {
  $string = filter_var($uncheckedPassword, FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, ["options"=>["regexp"=>"/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}/"]]); // Checks the password against the regex on the form
  $string = filter_var($string, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS); // Removes HTML tags, etc replacing them with char codes
  return $string;
}

protected function checkIfUserExists() {
  // Set the initial status of user exists
  $userExists = false;
  // Open a connection to the database
  $con = Db::getInstance();

  // Prepare the query
  $checkIfUserExists = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users2 WHERE username=?");
  //Execute the query with the checked username
  $checkIfUserExists->execute([$this->checkedUserName]);
  // Set $userExists dependent on result
  if($checkIfUserExists->rowCount() !== 0) {
    $userExists = true;
  }
  return $userExists;
}
```

}

My LoginUser class:

```
class LoginUser extends User{

public function __construct($uncheckedUserName, $uncheckedPassword) {

  parent::__construct($uncheckedUserName, $uncheckedPassword);
}

private function getPasswordHashes() {
  // Only connect to the database when connection is needed
  $con = Db::getInstance();

  // Check if username and password match
  // Prepare the query
  $checkUser = $con->prepare("SELECT * from users2 WHERE username = ?");
  // Execute the query using an array to bind the parameter to ?
  $checkUser->execute([$this->checkedUserName]);

  return $checkUser;
}

public function getLogInResult() {
  // Initialise the results variable
  $resultsFound = 0;

  // Only proceed if the username actually exists
  if($this->checkIfUserExists()) {

    // Call the function to get the records that match the username
    $checkUser = $this->getPasswordHashes();

    // Check to see if exactly one match was found and verify the password
    if($checkUser->rowCount() === 1) { // Note this may not work in other databases - it does in MySQL
      foreach($checkUser as $user) {
        if(password_verify($this->checkedPassword, $user['passwordHash'])) {
          $resultsFound++;
        }
      }
    }
  return $resultsFound;
}
```

}
}

My RegisterUser class:

```
lass RegisterUser extends User{

private $checkedFirstName = '';
private $checkedLastName = '';

public function __construct($uncheckedUserName, $uncheckedPassword, $uncheckedFirstName, $uncheckedLastName) {

  parent::__construct($uncheckedUserName, $uncheckedLastName);
  $this->checkedFirstName = $this->sanitizeString($uncheckedFirstName);
  $this->checkedLastName = $this->sanitizeString($uncheckedLastName);
}

private function sanitizeString($uncheckedString) {
  $string = filter_var($uncheckedString, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

  return $string;
}

private function insertUserDetails() {
  // Hash the supplied password in preparation for insertion
  //$hashedPassword = password_hash($this->checkedPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  // Connect to the database
  $con = Db::getInstance();

  // Prepare the query
  $addUser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users2 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

  // Execute the query using an array to bind the parameters
  $addUser->execute([$this->checkedUserName, password_hash($this->checkedPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT), $this->checkedFirstName, $this->checkedLastName]);

  // Return the result
  return $addUser;
}

public function getRegisterResult() {
  // Initialise the variable to store the result state
  $result = false;

  // Only proceed if the username does not exist
  if(!($this->checkIfUserExists())) {
    $addUser = $this->insertUserDetails();

    // If the details were successfully added
    if($addUser->rowCount() === 1) {
      $result = true;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}
```

}

So, when completing the registration form, the `getRegisterResult()` function is called on a new `RegisterUser` object.  When logging in, the `getLoginResult()` function is called on a new `LoginUser` object but the result returns false...

Comment: we are not mentalist to figure out the code based on a description. provide your code if you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to my question, it doesn't matter which classes use password_hash and password_verify, if there's a match with the password to verify and the hash from the database it should return a positive result!

The issue was with `__construct()` for the `RegisterUser` class - the call to the parent passed in `$uncheckedLastName` rather than the `$uncheckedPassword` and therefore the password being set at registration was not what was supplied in the password field but that what was supplied in the LastName field!